# How to Replace for multibyte character in java

Tags: multibyte

I want to convert the multibyte space. Is there any way through which i can convert this into normal characters.

```
        String queryTerm = "DX- zzzz";
    queryTerm = queryTerm.replaceAll("\\s", "AND");
    System.out.println(queryTerm);

    String queryTermWithNormalSpace = "DX- zzzz";
    queryTermWithNormalSpace = queryTermWithNormalSpace.replaceAll("\\s+", "AND");
    System.out.println(queryTermWithNormalSpace);
```

First queryTerm has Multi-Byte SPACE(0x3000) due to it doesn't find space and it doesn't do replace, but second string gives me output with replacement.

What would be the regular expression to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Java 7:

```
queryTerm =
Pattern.compile("\\s",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).match‌​er(queryTerm).replac‌​eAll("AND");
```